# My json response is in two dimensional array so how would I display that response in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

Hi I am trying to display two dimensional array like in this image but not work my code please help me and my json respone is in image which i want to display in UITableView

[image]

```
-(void)getCategories

{

         Service *srv=[[Service alloc]init];

         NSString *str=@"http://streamtvbox.com/site/api/matrix/";//?country_code=91&phone=9173140993&fingerprint=2222222222";
         NSString *method=@"channels";
         NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

         [srv postToURL:str withMethod:method andParams:dict completion:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseObj)
         {
              NSLog(@"%@",responseObj);
              arrayCategories = [responseObj valueForKey:@"categories"];
         }];
   }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
       return arrayCategories.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ChannelCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [[arrayCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"categories"];

        return cell;
}
```

Comment: Currently what is displaying in your textLabel? In your answer you have fetched valueForKey "categories" which is not there in your response(As per your image of response)

Comment: nothig when i try to reload the table view it give an error like [__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to ins tance 0x7fd67d14a320

Comment: Yes exactly! Because in your response array there is not any key like "categories"

Comment: "categories" is may json key and so what I can display know?

Comment: One more thing I have noticed. As per your code,
arrayCategories = [responseObj valueForKey:@"categories"];
You have already fetched value for key "categories" then why you are again fetching it in your textLabel

Comment: Can you please update your question? Show me the exact API response which you are getting. Before assigning it to any array or dictionary. And also tell me what you want to display in your tableView?

Comment: response : {
    categories =     {
        1 = Entertainment;
        11 = NFL;
        13 = NHL;
        15 = Lifestyle;
        17 = Kids;
        22 = Music;
        23 = "Indian Channels HD";
        27 = NBA;
        3 = Documentary;
        4 = "Extra Time";
        5 = Movies;
        6 = News;
        7 = PPV;
        8 = Sports;
        9 = "Sports HD";
    };
    channels =     (
                {
            "cat_id" = 9;
            id = 745;
            image = "http://streamtvbox.com/apk/745.png";
            title = "SportsNet World HD";
        },

Comment: json response is like this and I want to display only categories in my tableview

Comment: Please check my answer below. I just executed your response in  tableView in one demo project. :)

Comment: yes but another issue coming reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7fca2a4fa200> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key categories.'

Comment: This should not be happened. Don't know what is wrong!

Comment: Okay got your problem. Just wait for a while let me update my answer.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Just change your textLabel line. Everything else remains same as above in your code.

Comment: which kind of change i do in my textLable line?

Comment: Check my answer! I just updated it. Replace your cell.textLabel line with my cell.textLabel line. And also don't forget to remove allValues while assigning your response to the array. Because now allValues not required.

Comment: which line is your line?

Comment: See my answer man! In that you will find cell.textLabel.text

Comment: not working same error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will help you,

You are doing some minor mistake, do something as below,

```
arrayCategories = [responseObj valueForKey:@"categories"]; //Which is already there in your code....
```

And while fetching value in your textLabel, write as below

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[arrayCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Do not write here valueForKey "categories".
Let me know if you still face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it the issue is in your response.In categories key you are not getting array , you are getting object.Paste exact log `NSLog(@"%@",responseObj);` that you get in your success block so that i can help you to sort it out.

Comment: so you need response of my json data?

Comment: @Birendra yes i need json

Comment: that issue was solved but another error is occurs
reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7fca2a4fa200> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key categories.'

Comment: @Birendra this will be obvious because the problem is due to json, can you send me exact json you print it out.

Comment: all json respone or which one i display in the table view?

Comment: @Birendra whole json as it you get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96787/discussion-between-bmindhacker-and-birendra).